# In vi/vim, is it possible to create a mapping to concatenate words to a search on the fly?

Tags: search, mapping, vi

This questions is best illustrated in an example.

Example sentence:

> Bob went to the store. Bob bought an apple. Bob left the store.

I put the cursor on "Bob" and hit * (shift-8) to search for "Bob" in the text.
Now I want to put the cursor on "store" and hit * (or any other key of my choosing) to now search for `/\<Bob\>\|\<store\>`.

The purpose of this is to avoid having to type each word individually.

Is this doable? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can record a macro to do this:

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> - record a macro in register `q`
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> - yank in word (new search term under cursor)
- <kbd>/</kbd> - start a search
- <kbd>`<C-R>`</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> - paste previous search term into new search
- <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd><</kbd> - add a literal `|` for "or" and `<` for matching the start of a word
- <kbd>`<C-R>`</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> - paste the yanked new search term into the new search
- <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>`>`</kbd><kbd>`<CR>`</kbd> - match the end of the work and do the search
- <kbd>q</kbd> - stop recording the macro

Then pressing <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> will append the word under the cursor to the previous search.

Of course, you could create a mapping instead if you prefer.

(Note that the first two keypresses (`<C-R>`) are Control-R whereas the third (`<CR>`) is carriage return/Enter.)